# How to get total video & image size from external SD card

Tags: android

I am trying to calculate total memory size (video & image) from external SD card. For example there is a method `MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(String path)`. From where I can get the URI and calculate the size audio files. By passing ..

```
private long getMedia(Uri uri) {
    Log.e("URI",uri+"");
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE };
    Cursor cursor = ((Activity) context).getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
    long size = DirectoryMediaSize.getMediaSize(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return size;
}
```

There is no such method like `MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUriForPath()`. So how can i calculate the size for (video & image) ???

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

```
                    Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
                    File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));

long check = ((imageFile.length() / 1024));
                    if (check < 5000)
                    {
                         // less then 5 mb
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                            // greater then 5 mb
                    }
```

**function getRealPathFromURI**

```
String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI)
    {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null)
        { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        }
        else
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: How can i get the contentURI of a sd card?

Comment: getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI) use this !

Comment: Sorry to say that i need total media size specific for video or image. I have sd card path.Is there any api or easy way to calculate it as i find it MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(String path) ??

Comment: first get all files than get size !